# To convert pdf to text using pdfparser

Tags: php, pdftotext

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);

require_once "pdfparser-master/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php";

$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();

$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('sample.pdf');  
$pages  = $pdf->getPages();

// Loop over each page to extract text.
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo $page->getText();
}
```

There is no error. But I'm not getting any output. Is anything Wrong?

Comment: try ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); - to get notices and warnings too - they might provide you more information

Comment: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); It also does not provide any error